# Why is the output always zero when the fractions are parenthesized? No matter what the input is

Tags: c++

Problem statement: 
A cookie recipe calls for the following ingredients:

- 1.5 cups of sugar.
- 1 cup of butter.
- 2.75 cups of flour.

The recipe produces 48 cookies with these amounts of the ingredients. Write a program that ask the user how many cookies he or she wants to make and then displays the number of cups of each ingredient needed for the specified number of cookies.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
    double sugar, butter, flour;
    int cookies;

    cout << "Enter the number of cookies you wish to make: ";
    cin >> cookies;

    sugar = (double)cookies*(1/32);
    butter = (double)cookies*(1/48);
    flour = (double)cookies*(11/192);

    cout << "Sugar: " << sugar << endl;
    cout << "butter: " << butter << endl;
    cout << "flour: " << flour << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `1/32` and other value 0, you wanted `1.0/32` or `1/32.0` or `1.0/32.0` etc

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> sugar = (double)cookies*(1/32);
> butter = (double)cookies*(1/48);
> flour = (double)cookies*(11/192);
> ```

all of them value 0 because you divide *int*

use float for at least one number in each division

you can also just divide by the right number for the two first cases, to multiply by 1 is useless

```
sugar = cookies/32.0;
butter = cookies/48.0
flour = cookies*(11.0/192);
```

But because the statement says 1.5 cups of sugar for 48 cookies it seems more coherent to use `sugar = cookies*1.5/48.0;` it is useless to simplify the numbers, the compiler does that at compile time and produces exactly the same code in the two cases.

Same for 2.75 cups of flour for 48 cookies, `flour = cookies*2.75/48;`

In case you want to use these formulas in several locations in your code it is more practical and safe to define constants like

```
const double sugar_per_cookie = 1.5/48;
const double butter_per_cookie = 1.0/48;
const double flour_per_cookie = 2.75/48;
```

again do not be afraid of cost at execution, the compiler will optimize. If you prefer you can also use `#define` for them but in that case warning to place the formulas between () to be compatible with any formula using them and to not produce a bad result because of operator precedence.

I also encourage you to check if `>>` success, if you do not enter a valid integer *cookies* is not set

```
if (!(cin >> cookies)) {
  cerr << "invalid value, abort" << endl;
  return -1;
}
```

So for instance:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void){
  std::cout << "Enter the number of cookies you wish to make: ";

  int cookies;

  if (!(std::cin >> cookies) or (cookies < 0)) {
    std::cerr << "invalid number of cookies, abort" << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  double sugar = cookies*1.5/48.0;
  double butter = cookies/48.0;
  double flour = cookies*2.75/48;

  std::cout << "Sugar: " << sugar << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Butter: " << butter << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Flour: " << flour << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ g++ -Wall c.cc
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./a.out
Enter the number of cookies you wish to make: 48
Sugar: 1.5
butter: 1
flour: 2.75
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./a.out
Enter the number of cookies you wish to make: 0
Sugar: 0
butter: 0
flour: 0
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./a.out
Enter the number of cookies you wish to make: 1
Sugar: 0.03125
butter: 0.0208333
flour: 0.0572917
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./a.out
Enter the number of cookies you wish to make: 10
Sugar: 0.3125
butter: 0.208333
flour: 0.572917
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./a.out
Enter the number of cookies you wish to make: -1
invalid number of cookies, abort
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./a.out
Enter the number of cookies you wish to make: aze
invalid number of cookies, abort
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Comment: Good point about the numbers but what are the odds that clueless professor will say 'you could have simplified the numbers you know'?

Comment: @john I hope none ;-) but a professor can check the student knows the compiler will do the work at compile time

Comment: A "clueless" prof could say anything, but a good prof would value readability and transparency of intent over premature optimisation (especially when the "optimisation" has no effect)

Comment: @GavinLock may be John has bad souvenir with a professor ? ;-)

Comment: One suggestion would be to add something like `const double base_cookies = 48;` and then `double sugar = 1.5 * cookies / base_cookies;`

Comment: @GavinLock but what about the 1.5 ? To be able to use the value several times it seems better to define `const double sugar_per_cookie = 1.5/48;` etc no ?

Comment: `base_cookies` would be used three times (there are 3 literal 48.0s) in the code above - but something like `sugar_per_cookie` would only be used once (in the calc for sugar), so unless pulling it out as was to self-document by "giving it a name", I don't think I would go that far. (Just my personal taste)

Comment: @GavinLock personal taste are very important when the subject is cooking :-)

Comment: @GavinLock I'm not criticising Bruno's answer which is completely correct. But we have plenty of examples on this site where the posters say 'my professor told me to do ...' followed by some gross misunderstanding of C++. A fairly recent example was a student whose professor told them that they would lose marks **unless** they used `while (!file.eof())` to read a text file. Another recent example was a professor who told their students that they should 'use ASCII' to compare two strings. This was actually in the text of the question, which the poster quoted for us.

Comment: @john yes that happens, what a pity :-(, recently the statement in a question was "2D array of pointers" to speak about an array of `char*` ...

Comment: @john I agree completely. My comment was for the benefit of the OP and other readers - and I interpreted yours the same way. I've been thinking about this a lot lately: On SO we see far too many students suffering under bad teaching. I know there *are* great teachers out there, but it occurs to me that students with great teachers are *less likely* to need to come to SO for help. So I wonder - how big is the "selection bias" that makes it sometimes *appear* that the future generation of software developers are doomed. Maybe we only see (and try to help) the unlucky few.  I really don't know.

Comment: @GavinLock I'm sure there is lots of selection bias here! Sometimes I'm shocked by the lack of understanding of newbies and I have to think back and wonder if I was ever like that. Many people simply don't have the mental faculties to be programmers, it's no bad reflection on them, abstract thought simply doesn't come naturally to most people. But because demand outstrips supply many people end up studying programming who aren't suited to it.

Answer (score 0):

To understand expression evaluation like this, you need to know three things

1. The types of literals and variables.
2. The order of evaluation of the sub-expressions.
3. The conversion rules that apply to expressions.

There's a lot more to integer literals than meets the eye, though for 'ordinary' numbers you can consider that all integer literals are of type `int`. Take a look at [cpprefernce](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) for more details.

Roughly speaking, sub-expression evaluation follows the BODMAS or PEMDAS rules. Obviously C++ has far more operators, which complicate matters. The principle is the same though. Again [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) has a thorough summary.

Lastly, there is the question of sub-expressions conversions. At the end, the result of the whole expression needs to be that of the type of the left hand side of the assignment operator. Before that, the sub-expressions may also undergo conversions. To simplify this, a sub-expression containing two different integral types will convert the smaller to the larger size. Sub-expressions containing integral and floating point values will convert to floating point. Once again [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) has all the details, this time not so easy to follow.

So what does this mean for your expressions?

Let's take

```
sugar = (double)cookies*(1/32);
```

`cookies`, `1` and `32` are all of type `int`. However, `cookies` is explicitly cast to `double`. Note here that the cast operator has higher precedence than multiplication, so `cookies` is converted to `double` and not the result of the rest of the expression.

So in terms of types we have

```
double coookies*(int 1/int 32)
```

As already noted, the result of the integer division is zero, so we have

```
double cookies*int 0
```

The zero is implicitly convreted to zero double

```
double cookes*double 0.0
```

And the final result is zero double

(Note that the order of evaluation could be different as it is not specified, I'll spare you a fourth cppreference link).
(Note 2 for code like this the compiler will optimize sub-expressions. Even with no optimization I see the subexpression `1/12` gets evaluated as `0` on Compiler Explorer, and with high optimization the compiler can do all of the evaluation. This does not change the concepts here).

So what should you do? I would suggest doing as @bruno says and simply using floating point literals.